# JQuery Chain 2 Api Calls in a function

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I am new to JQuery and I'm stuck at how to do one API call to validate a user input, and then if the input validation returns true I want to do another Api call.

Unfortunately, my current code below does not work, as the validationFlag is immediately processed as false, before the first Api call is run.

I am using Kendo UI in a C# MVC app but it appears to be written in JQuery.

```
    $("#SubmitButton").on("click", function() {

    let validatedFlag = false;

    let request = {
        url: "@Url.Action("validate", "Validation")",
        parameters: {
            number: $("#MyInputField").data("kendoTextBox").value()   // get from input field
        }
        onSuccess: function (e) {
                // Do Stuff
                validatedFlag = true;
        },
        onFailure: function (e) {
            // Do Stuff
            validatedFlag = false;
        }
    }

    ControllerRequest(request);


    // This never runs as it is immediately called when validatedFlag = false
    if (validatedFlag === true) {

        
        let request2 = {
            url: "@Url.Action("GetProducts", "Products")",
            parameters: {
                Id: 100
            },
            onSuccess: function (e) {
                console.log("success");
            },
            onFailure: function (e) {
                console.log("fail");
            }
        };

        ControllerRequest(request2);
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: put the second request call inside `onSuccess` function directly.

Comment: OK, I'll give it a try, it will look horrible though...

Comment: if it works then you can wrap the 2nd call code inside a function and call that function inside `onSuccess `. for more redability purpose.

Comment: Yesh that worked. I wrapped it in a function then called the function onSuccess. If you write up an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the second request call inside the `onSuccess()` like below:

```
$("#SubmitButton").on("click", function() {
    let validatedFlag = false;
    let request = {
        url: "@Url.Action("validate", "Validation")",
        parameters: {
            number: $("#MyInputField").data("kendoTextBox").value()   // get from input field
        }
        onSuccess: function (e) {
                callSecondRequest();
        },
        onFailure: function (e) {
            // Do Stuff
            validatedFlag = false;
        }
    }
    ControllerRequest(request);
});

function callSecondRequest(){
    let request2 = {
        url: "@Url.Action("GetProducts", "Products")",
        parameters: {
            Id: 100
        },
        onSuccess: function (e) {
            console.log("success");
        },
        onFailure: function (e) {
            console.log("fail");
        }
    };
    ControllerRequest(request2);
}
```

Note: `validatedFlag` is not needed as you can directly do stuff inside `onSuccess` or `onFailure` accordingly. It is only needed if you are doing something based on it. In the current code, it is not required at all.